# Regex: Lazy matching in nested groups

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, regex-group

I have this regex: `/{(?:{(?:.*?)?)?$/g`.

Notice that I'm trying to lazily match `.*?` in the innermost group.

But it doesn't behave the way I expect:

```js
const regex = /{(?:{(?:.*?)?)?$/g;

let match = "{{abc{".match(regex)
// expected: [ "{" ]
// actual: [ "{{abc{" ]

match = "{{abc{{".match(regex)
// expected: [ "{{" ]
// actual: [ "{{abc{{" ]

match = "{{abc{{def".match(regex)
// expected: [ "{{def" ]
// actual: [ "{{abc{{def" ]
```

I'm using this regex to match `{`, `{{` or `{{something` if it is at the end of a string (without taking into account multi-line strings)

It might be because the string is matched from left to right, but is there an elegant way to get the expected behavior?

EDIT:

Using the regex in the selected solution solves the above problem, but fails if the string after the last `{{` contains one or many `{` not following each other.

example:

```js
const regex = /{(?:{(?:[^{]*?)?)?$/g;

let match = "{{abc{{de{f".match(regex)
// expected: [ "{{de{f" ]
// actual: null

match = "{{abc{{de{f{g".match(regex)
// expected: [ "{{de{f{g" ]
// actual: null
```

Comment: `$` makes it match till the end. Regex engine parses the string from left to right, so it starts matching from the leftmost char it matches. Use `{(?:{(?:[^{}]*)?)?$`. Or `{{?[^{}]*$`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/g32JZb/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.*` you are matching everything, including `{`. You have to exclude it from the "innermost string" with a `[^{]`, and you may add here any character you also want to exclude:

`{(?:{(?:[^{]*?)?)?$`.

Check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/YIwnQr/1).

For the EDIT, you need to make one of the `{` optional, in order to be able to parse both `{{` and `{`.

`{(?:{?(?:[^{]*?)?)?$`.

Check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/dQByM2/1).

Comment: Now there's a new problem, I want to match `{` if it occurred once after `{{`, but that might need a look ahead. it looks complicated.

Comment: edit the question with an example of it.

Comment: I added an edit to the question.

Comment: Edited the answer. If you find helpful upvote, please.